# Paint region of cells Sudoku

Tags: android, algorithm, cell, paint, sudoku

I want to paint the square to which a sudoku number selected belongs.

This code is for print the rows and columns :

```
              //Pintem la fila del nombre seleccionat
            for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
                TextView child = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(i);
                if ((i/9)==x) {
                    //child.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#75FFEE"));
                    child.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.contornfonsblau));
                }
            }

            //Pintem la columna del nombre seleccionat
            for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
                TextView child = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(i);
                if ((i%9)==y) {
                    //child.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#75FFEE"));
                    child.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.contornfonsblau));
                }
            }
```

I wanted the same but for the square.

[EXAMPLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Elvl6.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can find which large square a number belongs to by dividing the x and y co-ordinates of the small square by 3 using integer division, since the large squares are 3x3 small squares.

So, do the same comparisons as above, but divide both sides by 3 beforehand. You also need to check both x and y:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
    TextView child = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(i);
    if ((((i/9)/3)==(x/3)) && (((i%9)/3)==(y/3))) {
       child.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.contornfonsblau));
    }
}
```

Of course, `(i/9)/3` could be simplified to `i/27`, but it's debateable whether that is more readable.

You can combine all 3 tests into a single for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
    TextView child = (TextView) parent.getChildAt(i);
    if(((i/9)==x) ||
       ((i%9)==y) ||
       ((((i/9)/3)==(x/3)) && (((i%9)/3)==(y/3)))) {
       child.setBackground(getDrawable(R.drawable.contornfonsblau));
    }
}
```